# So, I'm trying to make a custom textured item larger (version 1.16.4) but i just cant seem to figure out how to make it work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

Here's the block of text I've been using but I cant seem to figure out the problem

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "display": {
        "thirdperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [0, -90, 55],
            "translation": [0, 4.0, 0.5],
            "scale": [2, 2, 2]
        },
        "thirdperson_lefthand": {
            "rotation": [0, 90, -55],
            "translation": [0, 4.0, 0.5],
            "scale": [2, 2, 2]
        },
        "firstperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [0, -90, 25],
            "translation": [1.13, 3.2, 1.13],
            "scale": [2, 2, 2]
        },
        "firstperson_lefthand": {
            "rotation": [0, 90, -25],
            "translation": [1.13, 3.2, 1.13],
            "scale": [2, 2, 2]
        }
    },
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "swords/technoblade"
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the default scaling different for first- and third-person? Also, you might have to change the scaling to say `[ 2.0, 2.0, 2.0 ]` because sometimes Minecraft is picky about syntax

Comment: Are you using a custom texture? (I see the word "technoblade") Also, can you specify exactly what is happening? For example: item not rendering, not scaling up, etc.